# How to list columns of a Row?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
CREATE FUNCTION cs_refresh_mviews() RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    mviews RECORD;
BEGIN
    PERFORM cs_log('Refreshing materialized views...');

    FOR mviews IN SELECT * FROM cs_materialized_views ORDER BY sort_key LOOP

       -- How For columns of mviews?

    END LOOP;

    PERFORM cs_log('Done refreshing materialized views.');
    RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want get value of columns in mviews.
How browser columns of mviews use to For or While?
The same as:

```
For i=0 to mviews.columns.count step i++
    raise  mviews[i]
```

Comment: I don't understand you question: "How browser columns of mviews use to For or While?" Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Materialized Views, really? Are you on 9.3 already? 
Anyways your question is not very clear, are you trying to iterate for all the columns in each view?

The Information Schema and [information_schema.columns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-columns.html) in particular can be what you are looking for.

Assuming you have some `schema` and `name` fields in cs_materialized_views table, you can do something like that:

Declare another Record variable: `mcols RECORD;`

And put this inside your loop:

```
FOR mcols IN (SELECT ordinal_position, column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = mviews.schema AND table_name = mviews.name ORDER BY ordinal_position) LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'View %, Column no. %: %', mviews.table_name, mcols.ordinal_position, mcols.column_name;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: I think the cited example from the OP comes directly from the 9.0 docs:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING